Writer- File>Send>Email Document Does Not Attach File in Thunderbird After Upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Again)
Okay: Chester Gillon's comment (thanks) below tells where the problem is: snaps cannot access the /tmp folder.
So How can LO be set to save the temp file somewhere the snap Thunderbird can access?
After I upgraded from the previous LTS to the 24.04.1 LTS and (same problem when I upgraded 2 years ago)
in Writer
File>Send>Email Document

(Thunderbird is the only email client)
Thunderbird is set as default email client.
Settings>Apps (Default Apps)>Thunderbird>Access Home Folder Yes

(Same happens in Calc it's a LO wide bug?)
Pops an error message:

File Attach
The file file:///tmp/lu173776aegs.tmp/lu173776aehv.tmp/noname.odt does
not exist so could not be attached to the message.

After OK clicked -
The email (in Thunderbird) opens with the file name as subject
But No file is attached.
I checked: file:///tmp/lu173776aegs.tmp/lu173776aehv.tmp/noname.odt
does exist.
Since this happened after the last LTS upgrade (no error msg displayed back then) and Then went away when I did a fresh install of that LTS,
I did a fresh install of this LTS.
No joy. Still no file attached.
In
FILES
right click > Email

does open an email with the file attached.
Suggestion from an old thread does not work.
I can't send libre office document as attachments

Open LibreOffice, navigate to Tools -> Options -> Internet -> Email
and set (eg. Thunderbird or Evolution as) default email client
(usually located in /usr/bin/thunderbird & /usr/bin/evolution).

I entered the path and Thunderbird, then removed it an left it blank. (Same as two years ago)
Is this a permissions issue? I can't see anything in Thunderbird's permissions that might help.
Is this a timing issue: Thunderbird looks for the file before LO has time to create it?
Where's the issue?
all versions are default distributions with Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.

Thunderbird 128.3.1esr (64-bit) - snap,

Writer --
Version: 24.2.6.2 (X86_64) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 420(Build:2)
CPU threads: 20; OS: Linux 6.8; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI: en-US
Ubuntu package version: 4:24.2.6-0ubuntu0.24.04.1
Calc: threaded ,

Or Ubuntu


Even if there is no fix, can someone explain (idiot level) what which software is supposed to do when to make this work.
Maybe I can trace down the problem if it is not a code problem. (only coding I ever did was decades ago with PHP and HTML before visual editing was possible.)
From the error message it appears that
Writer creates a temporary file in tmp folder (success)
then
Thunderbird tries to attach that file to an email as it opens a new email, but fails.

maybe already checked but have you got Thunderbird Mail selected in settings -> Default Applications?

With Thunderbird as a SNAP, the SNAP doesn't have permission to access the host /tmp directory. Accessing /tmp from snaps? has some information on this, but I not sure of how to fix the issue.

A workable work-around.
Set the LO tmp folder where Tbird can access it.
I set the LibreOffice temp fold to be Downloads/LOtmp.
Closed LO and Tbird.
Opened LO and it works:
Tbird opened an email with the attached file.
Not a real fix, but a real, doable work around.
Until the coders figure out how to allow Snaps to read files of other programs in a safe manner.
Question remains: is this work around putting LO or Tbird or other at risk, that ought to be avoided?
